# Create DB context in different project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

There is option to create DB which the DB context not allocated in the same MVC project,

i.e create one MVC in project A and the DB context in In project B which can use the model of model A

The reason is that I  want to access to the DB from different project without any dependence

Edit.

I've created this in project A and generate the view and controller by scaffold and its working,now what should I do in project B to access to this DB context?

```
namespace DiffDBContext2.Models
{
    public class Ad
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }


        public string FirstName { get; set; }


        public string LastName { get; set; }

    }

    public class AdModelDbContext : DbContext
    {


        public DbSet<ad> Ad { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what do you exactly want. But what I feel is that you want to have data access later as a separate project than your client (mvc). In this case you can have you dbcontext in  another project but you need to have connection string in both mvc and data access project. when executing it always request connection string from client.

Comment: Thanks You Qamar,this is exactly what I want.Voted UP! Currently I work with MVC5 and I create the model and add to it DB context and go to the controller and generate the controller and UI by scaffolding.if I want to use your suggestion can you please provide the steps how to that?since Im not sure how can I generate the project A if I have only the model,Thanks in advance!

Comment: To have a common model for both client and data layer create a third project of type class library and create all of your models there. then use this to create dbset<model> in context class of your data layer and use it in controller of client to generate scaffolded view based on model.

Comment: Thanks but I new to this topic can you please provide in your answer the steps?Thank you!

Comment: 1. Create a new solution in VS. 2. Create a new project with template of class library(call it models or something similar) 3. Create another class library (call it dataaccess) 4. Now create your mvc apllicaion call it web or something similar. Once these are created then create your model classes in model project. Then your data access project add a dbcontext with dbset<model>. Create necessary data access method as you need. Once thats done in you mvc project create a controller with dependency to data access class. and do necessary database operation through that.

Comment: Thanks please see my updated post.not sure how to proceed from here

Comment: Qamar- Can you help please?

Comment: what's project B here?

Comment: currently the DB context is in project A which allow me to use the scaffold but its should be there I guess since the DB context is part of DAL correct?so how should I add the DB context to project B to remove the DAL from A and make it work,I can share my project with one drive if its OK.Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52459/discussion-between-qamar-and-shopia-t)